# grizzly tutorial java.net.ConnectException

Tags: java, grizzly

I followed this tutorial : https://javaee.github.io/grizzly/quickstart.html
(it contains 4 files: ClientFilter,EchoClient, EchoFilter, EchoServer)

The aim of this tuto is First that the server echo its class name. This step went well. **The second step is to echo an input using EchoClient.java This step sends an error that I don't know how to fix. The server didn't not run.**

here is the file :

```
package grizzly.tuto;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.Connection;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.Grizzly;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainBuilder;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportBuilder;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.StringFilter;

/**
 * The simple client, which sends a message to the echo server
 * and waits for response
 */
public class EchoClient {
    private static final Logger logger = Grizzly.logger(EchoClient.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {

        Connection connection = null;

        // Create a FilterChain using FilterChainBuilder
        FilterChainBuilder filterChainBuilder = FilterChainBuilder.stateless();
        // Add TransportFilter, which is responsible
        // for reading and writing data to the connection
        filterChainBuilder.add(new TransportFilter());
        // StringFilter is responsible for Buffer <-> String conversion
        filterChainBuilder.add(new StringFilter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        // ClientFilter is responsible for redirecting server responses to the standard output
        filterChainBuilder.add(new ClientFilter());

        // Create TCP transport
        final TCPNIOTransport transport =
                TCPNIOTransportBuilder.newInstance().build();
        transport.setProcessor(filterChainBuilder.build());

        try {
            // start the transport
            transport.start();

            // perform async. connect to the server
            Future<Connection> future = transport.connect(EchoServer.HOST,
                    EchoServer.PORT);
            // wait for connect operation to complete
            connection = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            assert connection != null;

            System.out.println("Ready... (\"q\" to exit)");
            final BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            do {
                final String userInput = inReader.readLine();
                if (userInput == null || "q".equals(userInput)) {
                    break;
                }

                connection.write(userInput);
            } while (true);
        } finally {
            // close the client connection
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }

            // stop the transport
            transport.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}
```

here is the log :

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl$Sync.innerGet(SafeFutureImpl.java:363)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.get(SafeFutureImpl.java:264)
>       at grizzly.tuto.EchoClient.main(EchoClient.java:54)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>       at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
>       at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOConnectorHandler.onConnectedAsync(TCPNIOConnectorHandler.java:210)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOConnectorHandler$1.connected(TCPNIOConnectorHandler.java:158)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOConnection.onConnect(TCPNIOConnection.java:258)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:530)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:103)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:415)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:384)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:348)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:279)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)`

**EchoClient.java:54 corresponds to this java file - line :** 
`connection = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

**For you information : Eclipse warns that**

> Connection is a raw type. References to generic type Connection should be parameterized`

**I use :**
 - grizzly-framework-2.4.3.jar
 - JDK-11

**If you have any idea to help or where to look I'll appreciate. thanks**

Comment: Please add details, show a few lines of code and point out which line threw the exception.

Comment: All 4 files were in the link provided. But ok, i'll edit the msg :)

Comment: People who come to answer your question should have a motivation. People take their work time or personal time to read, understand, and answer questions without any expectations. Make their work simpler.
Meanwhile I would recommend reading this.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The error means that EchoClient tries to open a connection, but nothing is accepting the connection. You must first start up EchoServer, and then while it is running, also start EchoClient.

Comment: thanks to both of you Aditya for helping with my question (I understand and do better) and Jesper. It does make sense… and it certainly work just fine !